# PHP - Using a variable as the index for a $_GET[''] statement

Tags: php, arrays, variables, get

I have an array, *anArray*, that I loop through, like so:

```
foreach ($anArray as $key) {

    echo $_GET[$key];

}
```

I get numerous errors saying:

> Undefined index: $key

Which is true, but I don't know how to get my PHP to recognise $key is a variable, and not just a string.

If I print out the list of the $_GET $key => $value pairs, and a list of $anArray, they both contain at least some of the same values.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Many thanks.

Comment: This should work as is. `$arr[$var]` is supported perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm not trying to get the value from the array, I'm trying to get the value from the $_GET query, when the index is equal to a value in the array.

Answer (score 1):

It already does recognize $key as a var, your syntax is correct, you can eliminate the error this way:

Check if $_GET array has $key in it first like this:

```
if array_key_exists($key, $_GET) {
    echo $_GET[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you have values in $anArray that do not exist as indexes in $_GET.

For instance,

```
http://someserver/somepage.php?var1=this&var2=that
```

Will result in a $_GET like:

```
array(
  'var1' => 'this',
  'var2' => 'that'
)
```

So, if $anArray is like:

```
array('var1','var2','var3');
```

Your loop will work fine for **var1** and **var2**, but when it gets to **var3** it will issue the *undefined index* error.

If you can't know whether all the elements in $anArray are going to exist in $_GET, and you just wish to suppress the error notice, the usual approach is to wrap your execution block in an isset(); wrapper:

```
foreach ($anArray as $key) {
  if (isset($_GET[$key])) {
    echo $_GET[$key];
  }
}
```

Or use array_key_exists() as suggested by @HappyMary.